# Launch Dropbox from my app Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I want to call the dropbox app in my app Android using the Intent.
What I have to do???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `PackageManager` and [`getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) with the package name for DropBox, i.e `com.dropbox.android`. You will get a [PackageManager.NameNotFoundException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.NameNotFoundException.html) if Dropbox isn't installed.

Comment: I tried this:    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android"); but it doesn't work!!!

Comment: Do you have DropBox Installed?

Comment: Sorry....it is work!!!I tried in an other mobile without Dropbox...Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to share a file by lauching dropbox , you can use ACTION_SEND  :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");
```

you can also send a specific file :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType(fileType); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(file.getPath()));  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title"));
```

See this [article](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/02/a-call-to-action-action_send-that-is/) to understand the convention behind ACTION_SEND.

Comment: Uri.parse(file.getPath()) does not work. Please use Uri.fromFile(file) instead. Also there is a missing close bracket on the final line of the code. I've tried to edit the answer but my edit was rejected.