# How to share images in android?

Tags: android

I have installed Dropbox, Gmail plus in my android. I have read the article [Launch Dropbox from my app Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284294/launch-dropbox-from-my-app-android/11284342#11284342).

I hope to share my images to  Dropbox or Gmail plus , I think the following code will popup a menu let me select Dropbox ,Gmail plus or othe App to share my images, but I get a prompt infomation: **No applications can perform the action**. Why?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have to use `intent.putExtra ()`

Please read the following [article](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Answer (score 2):

2 changes recommended to implement share in your picture app :

In the manifest, add this to the filter for the action you want to include in the menu that will drop-down when the user taps the [standard share icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM36h.png) from the standard action bar:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

In your OnCreate/OnResume for the activity which contains the manifest filter above... 
handle the SEND :

```
   if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(
       getIntent().getAction()) && getIntent().getType() != null) {
       ...
    }
```